# Floating font in android device

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

i'm have an issue where the font is actually floating for some reason. 
Here is the sample:(Top = google chrome desktop, Bottom  = Samsung Internet borwser, but also same thing happens in chrome android):
[image: Floating Font]

I am using font Helvetica Neue in React, applying it to body:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url(./assets/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Lt.otf), url(./assets/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd.otf);
}


body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}
```

So any of you have any idea why is this happens? And hope have solution also. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So in the end i downloaded the fonts from: https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/helvetica-neue-lt-std. Then test it using the following code, open in the desktop browser and android browser. Apparently, for some reason the helvetica neue lt std, the one that i am using is the only font with problem. Checkout the screenshot.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style-helvetica-neue-lt.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style-helvetica-neue.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
      .container {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: block;
      }
      .arial {
        font-family: "arial";
      }
      .helvetica-neue-lt {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue LT Std 45 Light";
      }
      .helvetica-neue {
        font-family: "Helvetica 43 Light Extended";
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <span class="container helvetica-neue">Test Helvetica Neue</span>
    <span class="container helvetica-neue-lt">Test Helvetica Neue LT</span>
    <span class="container arial">Test Arial</span>
    <span class="container times-new-roman">Test Times New Roman</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]